# Question regarding the quotient of a group with it’s centre.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

It’s known that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. This implies that $Z(G)=G$, which in turn implies that $G/Z(G)$ is trivial. Does this mean that if the quotient group $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then it’s order is $1$?
More specifically, if $|G/Z(G)|=p$ for a prime $p$, then does it imply that $p=1$?

Comment: Well, $1$ isn't prime. So if $|G/Z(G)|=p$ prime then this is a contradiction so find your original assumption and conclude that it is false, rather than conclude that $p=1$.

Comment: Yes yes, this was just an example...like had it been given that the quotient group is cyclic and of order n, would it imply that n=1? If so, then what is the significance of considering the order of the quotient group to be a prime number(hence cyclic), and not discarding the case altogether?

Comment: Yes, if the quotient is cyclic of order $n$ then $n=1$. It would be helpful if you could add a specific example, then we can see what the author is saying rather than trying to guess abstractly like this :-)

Comment: This came as a result to be proven: If G/Z(G) is cyclic, then G is abelian.

Comment: Or, say if we are given a group of some order and we are to draw some conclusions about the order of the centre of the group...suppose a group is order 35, so the order of the centre can either be 1, 5(prime), 7(prime) or 35.

Comment: If $|G|=35=5\times7$ then the order of the center is $1$ or $35$. To see this, suppose otherwise. Then $|Z(G)|$ is $5$ or $7$, so $G/Z(G)$ is $7$ or $5$, and so prime. Hence, $G$ is abelian, so $G=Z(G)$, so $|Z(G)|=35$, a contradiction. [This is kind of what I was saying in my first comment: you conclude a contradiction here.]

Comment: I am  struggling to understand exactly what you are  asking here. You seem to be asking does the fact that a group is trivial imply that the order of the group is $1$. Yes, when we say that a group is trivial we mean precisely that its order is $1$.

Comment: My question was that if the quotient group G/Z(G) is given to be cyclic and of order n, would it imply that n=1?

Comment: @USSeR Yes, that is what Derek is saying. I have always found the proof of this theorem to be kind of funny.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand what you asking. You have said that you know that $G/Z(G)$ cyclic implies that $Z(G)=G$. So you are asking does $Z(G)=G$ imply what $G/Z(G)$ has order one. The answer seems to be obviously yes.

Comment: Yes @DerekHolt that is it...but my point is that if ultimately the order comes out to be 1, then what is the point of considering the order to be some n or p or something, and not just omit the case as trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question.** If the quotient group $G/Z(G)$ is given to be cyclic and of order $n$, would it imply that $n=1$?

**Answer.** Yes. As we know from the OP, if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. Therefore, if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $G=Z(G)$, and so $G/Z(G)$ is trivial, i.e. $|G/Z(G)|=1$.

As an example application: if $|G|=35=5\times7$ then the order of the center is $1$ or $35$. To see this, suppose otherwise. Then $|Z(G)|$ is $5$ or $7$, so $|G/Z(G)|$ is $7$ or $5$, and so prime, and so cyclic. Hence, $G$ is abelian, so $G=Z(G)$, so $|Z(G)|=35$, a contradiction.